# ESP32 device not discovered in phone Bluetooth

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, arduino-esp32

I am testing an ESP32 application by provisioning the WiFi credentials over BLE uaing a number of phones and found that in many of them, the ESP32 does not show up in the phone's bluetooth at all. It has worked on these phones: Samsung S9, Samsung S6, iPhone 6s. But it has not worked on Samsung A32, Samsung A72, Xiaomi... and undoubtedly, many more.

The code I'm using is jut the standard ESP Jumpstart example code for unified provisioning, using the BLE selection.

ESP-IDF 4.3.1.

See attached for menu config bluetooth settings:

[image]

Is it possible that some phones with Bluetooth 5.0 do not have BLE? My understanding is that BT 5.0 is 100% BLE. The only Bluetooth that is a bit dodgy is 4.2 where it's optional. Even in 4.0 it's all Low Energy.